# Custom binary operations and getattr

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datamodel

I would like to implement a class with custom binary operators, such that

```py
class One:
    def __lt__(self,other):
        return 1 < other
```

Python seems to be able to automatically create the *reverse* operation for the operators `>, >=, <, <=`, however, if I use the `getattr()` method instead, `NotImplemented` is returned:

```py
>>> a = One()
>>> a < 2
True
>>> 2 > a # Works without explicit implementation
True

# Now using the getter:
>>> getattr(a, '__lt__')(2)
True
>>> getattr(2, '__gt__')(a) # Does not work as above
NotImplemented
```

What would be the proper way to make the getter work as well in this case?
I know that for other operators, there is the respective reverse magic method, but the four mentioned above do not seem to have that.

Comment: Python doesn't make those attributes exist, it deals with their absence. If you want all of the comparison methods to exist, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering

Comment: `getattr(2, '__gt__')` retrieves the `__gt__` operator for POD integers and invokes it with an argument that doesn't inherit from `Integer`. That's something different than some auto-generated `__gt__` oeprator on class `One`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__